# When running my service, the service receives the request SERVER_CONTROL_INTEGORATTE from service control manager for every one minute

Tags: windows-services, operating-system, windows-server-2008, service-control-manager

When running my service in windows 2008 server machine,  the service receives the request SERVER_CONTROL_INTEGORATTE from service control manager for every one minute so he actual functionality of services is not getting executed. In that particular machine only I am facing this problem, in other machines its working fine.
Some links suggest that this problem is due to firewall, even if I turn off the firewall I am facing this problem.
Please suggest your ideas to resolve this problem.

Comment: You mean [SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). What are you returning from that request?

Comment: In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683240(v=vs.85).aspx) it is recommended to return NO_ERROR when service receives this request. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? What is not working or not working as you expect?

Comment: I am returning NO_ERROR only.The service continuously receiving SERVER_CONTROL_INTEGORATTE request from SCM so handling SERVER_CONTROL_INTEGORATTE is only geeting executed in my service and other part of code in my service is not getting executed.Why the SCM continously sending this request to my service? What could be the problem, whether some other application causing this problem?

Comment: Not only my service all the services running in that machine are facing this problem.What could be the problem with that machine.In other server 2008 machines my service is running properly.